Limit of Hessian of the distance function in constant curvature spaces
I am reading Peter Petersen's Riemannian Geometry 3rd edition. I am stuck in the proof of Theorem 5.5.8. I am unable to arrive at the conclusion given in the last line i.e., $\lim\limits_{r\to 0} \mathrm{Hess}~r = 0$.

Given the context just before the theorem, it is my understanding that the limit of $\mathrm{Hess}~r$ exists iff $\lim\limits_{r\to 0} \frac{g_r}{r}$ exists and they're both equal if they exist. Apart from this, I suspect that the limit being zero is dependent on the constant curvature assumption but I have had no luck figuring it out. I understand that there is something very silly that I may be missing.
Thank you for you help.

I'm not sure at the moment how to rigorously state this (maybe the expansion of the metric in exponential coordinates, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_coordinates), but near $r = 0$ the metric $g_r$ should look like $r^2 dS$ ($dS$ the unit sphere metric), and hence $g_r/r \to 0$. By the preceding proposition, this limit is equal to the Hessian's limit, hence that's also zero.

@Chris ``near r=0 the metric $g_r$ should look like $r^2 dS$", this is essentially what the first two equations in the image read. But I'm not entirely sure how one calculates the limit or even what those limits allude to? Also, since you did not use constant curvature assumption, is it always true that lim Hess r = 0?

Have you tried the flat case?

@Deane In the flat case, everything is zero even before taking limits, so I'm not sure how helpful that is.

If $r$ is the distance function from a point, its Hessian is not zero.

Note that $r$ is not smooth at $p$. It's also a nice exercise (unless Petersen already proves it) to answer the following question: If $r$ is the distance function from a smooth submanifold, when is it a smooth function in a neighborhood of the submanifold and what can you say about the submanifold if  $\operatorname{Hess} r$ vanishes on it?

@Deane My apologies, I made a stupid mistake the last time. Here's the calculation on $\mathbb{R}^n$:
$\mathrm{Hess}~r (\partial_i ,\partial_j) = \partial_i \partial_j r = \frac{r^2 \delta^i_j - x^ix^j}{r^3} $.
Using spherical coordinates for $n$ dimension, I arrived at the same term
$ \frac{g_r}{r} (\partial_i, \partial_j) = r \mathrm{ds}_{n-1}^2 (\partial_i, \partial_j) = \frac{r^2 \delta_i^j-x^ix^j}{r^3} $.
This limit as $r\to 0$ doesn't exist, right?

Right. The book is wrong.

Side comments: For $r>0$ the Hessian is the second fundamental form of the level set. The differential equation it satisfies is a Riccati equation and is essentially equivalent to the Jacobi equation. Both of these types of ODEs have classical comparison theorems (e.g., Sturm comparison theorems) and are form the basis of what’s known as comparison geometry. I’m pretty sure Peterson’s book gives onto this well since hes an expert in this.

Hello @Deane, sorry for the late reply. That was a bit anticlimactic as I kept thinking I was missing something silly and that the limit is too obvious. Thank you for taking the time to explain it to me. I am now curious about how the proof of the theorem works, since he used the limit essentially as an initial condition to a differential equation. Anyways, thank you for your time and patience.

Here's one approach: I like to use a parallel frame along each geodesic. Let $(e_1, \dots, e_n)$ be a parallel orthonormal frame along a radial geodesic. You can write $A$ as a matrix with respect to the frame. Let $J$ be a matrix-valued function such that $A = J^{-1}J$. You can check that $J(0) = 0$, $J'(0) = I$, and $$J'' + kJ = 0. $$ On the other hand, you can write down an explicit solution to this. By the uniqueness theorem for ODEs, that's the only solution. Finally, verify that $g = JJ^t$ (might be $J^tJ$) is the metric with respect to exponential coordinates.

What is A here?
